# Problem with parsing elements inside a 2d array

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, multidimensional-array

Kind of new to java and coding in general so this may be a stupid question, however, I am stuck, and could use some help!

The exercise wants me to pick out how many guests are over the age of 18 on a guest list. I have a String array that contains their name and age. Because of the String array, I can not compare the age as integers. I suppose I have to parse the age into an Integer but can not get a hold of it. My code may have problems with syntax and so on but for now I just want help with the parsing bit.

Here is my code:

```
public static void statistics()
  {

    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int alder = 0;

    String[][] guestList = {{"Adam Ason", "35"},
                            {"Berta Bson", "70"},
                            {"Ceasar Cson", "12"},
                            {"Derta Dson", "20"},
                            {"Erta Eson", "54"},
                            {"Ferta Fson", "26"},
                            {"Gerta Gson", "59"},
                            {"Herta Hson", "72"},
                            {"Irta Ison", "14"},
                            {"Jerta Json", "32"},
                          };


    int antalgaster = guestList.length;
    System.out.println("Number of guests: " + antalgaster + " ");

      for(int i = 0; i < guestList.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < guestList.length; j++){
          if(guestList[j] >= 18){ 
            counter1 = counter1 + 1;

        }
      }
    }
      System.out.println("Number of guests over the age of 18: " + counter1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The age is the second value, that will be `guestList[i][1]`

The value is a string, so you can parse it to an int.

Note that this is the happy flow, as you have strings that you can convert to an int. If you are not certain, `Integer.parseInt` can throw a *NumberFormatException* and you would have to account for that using a try/catch mechanism.

You are not using all the variables in the code, but you could write it for example like this.

```
int counter = 0;

String[][] guestList = {{"Adam Ason", "35"},
        {"Berta Bson", "70"},
        {"Ceasar Cson", "12"},
        {"Derta Dson", "20"},
        {"Erta Eson", "54"},
        {"Ferta Fson", "26"},
        {"Gerta Gson", "59"},
        {"Herta Hson", "72"},
        {"Irta Ison", "14"},
        {"Jerta Json", "32"},
};


int antalgaster = guestList.length;
System.out.println("Number of guests: " + antalgaster + " ");

for (int i = 0; i < guestList.length; i++) {
    int age = Integer.parseInt(guestList[i][1]);
    if (age >= 18) {
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of guests over the age of 18: " + counter);
```

Output

```
Number of guests: 10 
Number of guests over the age of 18: 8
```